# How to block apache2 root and it's default page

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have set apache2 root. It's `.htaccess` file is:

```
# Refuse direct access to all files
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Yet it still shows me default index:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

How to disable this default index or better block apache2 root?

Answer (score 0):

> `How to disable this default index or better block apache2 root?`

You can use this mod_rewrite rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ - [F]
```

Comment: No effect, still showing default page. Is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` somehow wrong: http://pastebin.com/vnes4fB0 ?

Comment: You need to place this rule in `/home/user/storage/websites/.htaccess`

Comment: No effect. Still getting default page.

Comment: Do you know if mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and working?